# VSFTPD connect from external IP

Tags: networking, 18.04, iptables, vsftpd

I have VSFTPD installed on my Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, cant connect from public IP. Here is my config:

```
listen=YES
listen_ipv6=NO
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
local_umask=022
dirmessage_enable=YES
use_localtime=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
xferlog_file=/var/log/vsftpd.log
xferlog_std_format=YES
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty
pam_service_name=vsftpd
userlist_file=/etc/vsftpd.userlist
userlist_deny=NO
chroot_local_user=YES
allow_writeable_chroot=YES
user_sub_token=$USER
local_root=/media/veracrypt4
rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/vsftpd.crt
rsa_private_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.key
ssl_enable=YES
ssl_tlsv1=YES
ssl_sslv2=YES
ssl_sslv3=YES
allow_anon_ssl=NO
force_local_data_ssl=YES
force_local_logins_ssl=YES
ssl_ciphers=HIGH
pasv_enable=YES
#pasv_address=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
#pasv_addr_resolve=YES
pasv_min_port=40000
pasv_max_port=50000
```

I configured iptables

```
-P INPUT DROP
-P FORWARD DROP
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-N f2b-postfix
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443,25,587,465,110,995,143,993,4190 -j f2b-postfix
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 587 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 110 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 995 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 143 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 993 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 21 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 137 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 138 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 139 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 445 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 192.168.1.0/24 -p udp -m udp --dport 137 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 192.168.1.0/24 -p udp -m udp --dport 138 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 192.168.1.0/24 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 139 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 192.168.1.0/24 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 445 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 21 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 20 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 20,21,40000:50000 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 20 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 21 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 990 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 989 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 20 -j ACCEPT
-A f2b-postfix -s xx.x.xxx.x/32 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A f2b-postfix -j RETURN
-A f2b-postfix -j RETURN
```

and here is my router configuration:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qX8hH.jpg

Still can`t connect, just get 500 POST error or Incorrect Login. Local connect works well. Thanks a lot for help!

Comment: Try nmap -sS <vstftpdServerIP> from Public side and post it to your question.

Comment: s1mmel, here is Not shown: 988 closed ports
PORT    STATE    SERVICE
21/tcp  open     ftp
22/tcp  open     ssh
23/tcp  open     telnet
25/tcp  open     smtp
80/tcp  open     http
110/tcp open     pop3
143/tcp open     imap
443/tcp open     https
465/tcp filtered smtps
587/tcp open     submission
993/tcp open     imaps
995/tcp open     pop3s

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 103.86 seconds

Comment: So the port is open from the outside. next step, pls. try to telnet to your service. use telnet to find out if this works too. see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50324402/how-to-list-ftp-directories-using-telnet